# Getting rid of python error `attempted relative import with no known parent package` while debugging in vscode

Tags: python, python-import, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I created `workspace_folder`, cloned a github `repo` (folder name) which has `repo_module` folder, which in turn has `train.py` and `algo.py`:

```
workspace_folder
|
+-- repo
     |
     +-- train.py
     |
     +-- algo.py
```

The repo's readme asks to run:

```
python -m repo_module.train
```

which I am able to run from within `repo` folder:

```
workspace_folder/repo$ python -m repo_module.train
```

But I want to debug the `train.py` in vscode. I opened `train.py` and started debugging with `Python: Current File` configuration. But it started giving me following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

for line `from . import algo` in `train.py`.

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) suggests that we need to do some changes to the code. I was thinking if I can make any changes to vscode debug `launch.json` and make it work. I tried to set `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/repo"` in `launch.json` but it gave same error. So, for now I have replaced all `from .`  (space after dot `.`) with empty string in all files (converting all `from . import abc` to `import abc`) and `from .` (no space after `.`) to `from`  in all files(converting all `from .abc` to `from abc`) and am able to debug it. But I was able to guess if I can do away with modifying code and configuring in vscode `launch.json`. Is it possible.

(Also note that my changes seem to have worked as all py files are "directly" inside `repo` folder and there is no subfolder inside `repo` folder.)

Comment: So basically I have to make changes to code merely for debugging? I cannot debug by specifying some config in vscode?

Comment: @Rnj  -When importing other files, VS Code looks for the file in the parent folder of the imported file by default, so please use "_import algo_" in the file "train.py".

Comment: Yeah ended up doing that only. But point is that I dont want to modify py files as there may be a lot of them. I felt there should be some config in vscode which will allow to fix it.